# DefaultHttpClient response code 400

Tags: java, httpclient

http://acm.hdu.edu.cn/showproblem.php/../../../data/images/con208-1004-1.JPG

This is the url, if you copy it to the brower, it works well. But when I use the apache HttpClient to download this img.

```
HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
```

I can't download it. I think it's because of the "../" , But in my program, I have to use this url.

Comment: The server probably checks some headers that you do not add

Comment: Could you post the full code you're using? Are you encoding the url?

Comment: Status code 400 is 'Bad Request'. Usually you get it if the request is faulty somehow. Please post more relevant code.

Comment: The request doesn't make sense, because you have only 1 folder before the 3 `..`. I think that you should clean the URL before using it to HttpClient.

Comment: You can see the code by Mark. I think the problem is the wrong url.

Answer (score 0):

Response 400 means you didn't ask in the right way to httpClient...

i put next a simple attempt:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;

import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;



public class  a {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws ClientProtocolException, IOException{

      HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
      HttpGet request = new HttpGet("http://acm.hdu.edu.cn/data/images/con208-1004-1.JPG");
      HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);

      // Get the response
      InputStream inputStream = response.getEntity().getContent();

      OutputStream outputStream = null;

        try {
            // read this file into InputStream 

            // write the inputStream to a FileOutputStream
            outputStream = 
                        new FileOutputStream(new File("C:/test.holder-new.jpg"));

            int read = 0;
            byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];

            while ((read = inputStream.read(bytes)) != -1) {
                outputStream.write(bytes, 0, read);
            }

            System.out.println("Done!");

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (inputStream != null) {
                try {
                    inputStream.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            if (outputStream != null) {
                try {
                    // outputStream.flush();
                    outputStream.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        }
    }  
}
```

pls also notice that DefaultHttpClient is deprecated. You can replace this:

```
HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
```

with:

```
HttpClient client = HttpClientBuilder.create().build();
```

this works to me, let me know if it helps.

Comment: My code is similar with yours.Your code can work, because you haven't use this url in your code :"http://acm.hdu.edu.cn/showproblem.php/../../../data/images/con208-1004-1.JPG"